# Clicking "OK" on pop up closes Blender

Tags: python, scripting, blender-internal-render-engine

I am new to Blender and just started scripting for our pipeline. I have written a small script which when run sets up the scene unit settings. The script is run from a button in a panel.

To let the user know that the script has been run, a popup appears with a single "OK" button.

Whenever I click the button it closes Blender.

*Edit*: Blender also closes if I click elsewhere (not on the OK button)

Can anyone tell me why? Or tell me how to write this correctly?

Here's the code:

```
class SceneSettings(bpy.types.Operator):

  bl_idname = "la.scene_settings"
  bl_label = "Scene Settings Set Up"

  def execute(self, context):
    scene = bpy.context.scene
    scene.unit_settings.system = 'METRIC'
    scene.unit_settings.scale_length = 0.5
    context.window_manager.invoke_props_dialog(self,  width=175, height=50)
    return {'FINISHED'}
```

Thank you in advance,

Sofia

Comment: What do you need the dialog for? It doesn't seem to have any functionality.

Comment: I just want to let the user know that the script has been run, its more an information box than a dialog box. So all I want it a window with some text saying the script has run and an OK button to press to close the window. :)

Comment: The user will need to click a button to run this operator, I see no reason why to confirm the execution with a dialog. You should use `self.report(...)` you if you really want to inform the user. BTW: Do you know that you can modify the `startup.blend`? You can activate the metric system there once and it will be used as default for all new files you create.

Comment: Thank you for the reply!
I would very much like to have a pop up instead of self.report because the user may not have the "info" bar dragged down to see the output.  I like to give feedback to the users - especially when the scripts get more complex - to inform them that the script had been run succesfully.
I could write a script that opens a file on our network and saves it as the start up file, but then it will clear settings the user have already set.

Comment: It doesn't need to be dragged down, `self.report({'INFO'}, "Message")` will display between the render engine dropdown and the version info, as long as the operator is executed in the context of the 3D View (button in T- or N-toolshelf or spacebar menu).

Comment: hmm, you must have a different set up than me, because I dont see the message unless I drag down the top bar. Thank you for your help anyway. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to misunderstand how operators work. If there's supposed to be a props dialog, it is displayed **before** the operator execution. More specifically, in the **invoke** phase:

```
poll(cls, context) -> invoke(self, context, event) -> execute(self, context)
```

The poll classmethod of an operator is used to determine if the context allows the operator to run at all. If the context is not suitable (wrong area type, no object selected, ...), it needs to `return False`. You won't be able to run this operator until there's a valid context (not only from a button, but also spacebar menu and Python console). Operators in panels (=buttons) will be grayed out if polling fails.

What happens next depends on the execution context. If you run an operator from spacebar menu or by a button click, it will be usually `INVOKE_DEFAULT` and thus call `invoke()` of the operator. Notable about this method is, that an event object is passed to it. You need to **return the result of** `wm.invoke_props_dialog(self)` in `invoke()` to make the dialog work. It will open the dialog and wait for user input. If the user clicks outside the dialog, the operator will be aborted. If he/she clicks on OK, `execute()` will be called.

The `execute()` method of an operator contains the actual code of the operation. It is immediately executed if the execution context is `DEFAULT_EXECUTE`, which is the case for scripts and the Python console by default. There is usually no point in invoking the operator to get user input prior to the actual operation, and it's sometimes not even possible because of an incorrect context (an invocation from the Python console would run `invoke()` in the Python console, but a 3D View might be required). You would need to pass custom context along the execution context, like this:

```
bpy.ops.your.operator({'area': my_area}, 'INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

Your operator does not define `invoke()`, therefore `execute()` is called immediately. The scene parameters are changed, but then you call the props dialog. It can't be used here and does crash for that reason. It is not supported to display a dialog after an action (operators supporting undo can display something in the redo panel, but that's about it).

```
class SceneSettings(bpy.types.Operator):

    bl_idname = "wm.scene_settings"
    bl_label = "Scene Settings Set Up"

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        wm = context.window_manager
        return wm.invoke_props_dialog(self, width=175, height=50)

    def execute(self, context):
        scene = context.scene
        scene.unit_settings.system = 'METRIC'
        scene.unit_settings.scale_length = 0.5
        return {'FINISHED'}
```

A more appropriate way to inform the user is to use `self.report()`:

```
import bpy

class SceneSettings(bpy.types.Operator):

    bl_idname = "wm.scene_settings"
    bl_label = "Scene Settings Set Up"

    def execute(self, context):
        scene = context.scene
        scene.unit_settings.system = 'METRIC'
        scene.unit_settings.scale_length = 0.5
        self.report({'INFO'}, "Applied scene settings.")
        return {'FINISHED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Run this code in the *Text Editor*, then search for the operator in the 3D View spacebar menu.

[image: self.report() in info area on operator execution in 3D View context]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I had a feeling I was misunderstanding the concept. Now I get it. Its unfortunate that you cannot have a dialog box after an operation is run. Now I will have to make sure all my coworkers have the info bar visible to them :) thank you again.

Comment: what is "la" in "la.scene_settings" ?

Comment: Hmm that's very nice CoDEmanX - the screen short I mean. I wonder how to set that up as I dont have that showing at the moment. Its a great way to inform the user, I would never have thought of a pop up if I had known that was in the scene! Thank you for the screenshort:) Chebhou: its the initials of our production - it could have been anything.

Comment: Apparently reports are not displayed in the header anymore according to this: https://developer.blender.org/T26708

Comment: you can use : bpy.context.window_manager.popup_menu(draw_menu, title ='Info',icon = 'INFO') with draw_menu(self, context) to show a message at the end

Comment: ah thats a nice solution Chebhou - thanks a lot!

Comment: @SofiaElenaJakobsenManioudak: that's a fairly old report (2011). Works just fine in recent Blender versions. A popup menu is not a bad idea, and should work for this particular use case. It can be troublesome however if your operator relies on this popup somehow, as the execution order is potentially not sequential if you mix modal operator stuff with non-modal operators. The info bar is set up like in my screenshot by default, always visible. Did you modify the screen layout of your startup.blend by chance?